# move existing content in wordpress to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-s3, elastic-beanstalk

I have a existing wordpress website in Elasticbeanstalk AWS with auto scaling and load balancing and external RDS. while scaling policies are applied I will loose my existing data in EC2 instances so I want to keep it in such a place where I don't loose any configuration and data.
I do not want to use EFS and rather would like to use S3 for this to achieve I did not find a clear documentation in internet as to how to achieve it.
Can somebody help me with as to how to achieve it.

Note: I want to keep all my data which includes media files and wordpress config files as well on a whole view everything that I should have the wordpress running even the new instances are launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 isn't really made to be a file system, it's an object store. However...

**S3 as File System**

You can use [S3FS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), which makes S3 work like a file system. You take a risk though, as it might not work 100% perfectly.

**Media Files on S3**

Storing media files in S3 is no problem. You can use a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/s3/) (there are many, I can't recommend any in particular), copy existing files up there, S3 will serve the files directly reducing the load on your server. The plugin should upload new files to S3 automatically.

**Config Files on S3**

Storing config files in another bucket so you can auto-configure your Wordpress instance, sure, download it when the instance starts up using user data. This means you don't have to update your golden image constantly.

**EFS**

I know you said you don't want to use EFS, but why is that? This is exactly what EFS is made for, to be a shared file system. Performance scales with storage, so you do may need to store some large dummy files there to get performance up if you have a busy site.

AWS have [recommendations for Wordpress](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/wordpress-best-practices-on-aws/) that includes EFS.

Comment: can EFS be really the case to have a solution for this problem becuase my Idea of EFS is like we can only store the media files as s3 does.
Can you guide through the steps of how can I use EFS to fully upload my wordpress instance while I deploy or re deploy my wordpress application with changes and when a instance is launched newly how its going to work ? any documents or guidance will be great ... thank you very much

Comment: I have added a link to AWS best practices for Wordpress to the bottom of my answer.